# writing an array and group the contents using curly brackets

Tags: brackets

I want to write down the following equation:
[image]

my try is this:

```
\documentclass[preview, border=1pt, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    n + m =^{def} \left\{\begin{array}{rl} n+n + \ldots + n & \text{se } m > 0 \\ 0 & \text{se } m = 0\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to group the elements using curl brackets.

PS: I'd like also the background to be transparent and not white. I'm compiling with this:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape formula.tex && convert -resize 50% formula.png formula.png
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the square?

Comment: it signifies end of definition

Comment: I've never seen it used that way,

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use the ambient `cases` to write your "equation". Here you have a screenshot of my MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[n+m\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\begin{cases}
\underbrace{\sigma(\sigma(\ldots\sigma}_{m\text{ volte}}(n))) & \text{se $m>0$}\\
    n & \text{se $m=0$}.\qquad \square
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Comment:** Reading carefully the precious suggestions of the excellent users @egreg and @Mico my initial code has been modified.

Comment: I think the `case` environment is better than my solution with `\hspace`. I didn't know this environment. Thank you.

Comment: It should be `_{\text{$m$ volte}}` (the fact it works also without braces around `\text{...}` is irrelevant. Alternatively, `_{m\text{ volte}}`. I'd also use `\dotsm` instead of `\ldots`.

Comment: +1. In addition to incorporating @egreg's comment, you should also change `\text{se } m>0` to `\text{se $m>0$},` and `\text{se } m=0.` to '\text{se $m=0$}.`. Why? Mostly for reasons of semantic consistency: The clauses `se $m>0$` and `se $m=0$` are two standalone linguistic particles, and hence (at least from a LaTeX point of view) it's preferable to encase them in `\text` directives. The fact that both linguistic particles contain a math formula -- `$m>0$` and `$m=0$`, resp. -- does not change the fact that they are linguistic particles that shouldn't be broken up needlessly.

Comment: @Ahrtaler Slowly and patiently you'll certainly be better at it than me. I wish it with all my heart.

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't worked so I couldn't try. But this code should work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $n + m \overset{\text{def}}{=} \left\{\begin{array}{l}
    \underbrace{\sigma(\sigma(\ldots\sigma}_\text{m \text{volte}}(n))) \hspace{5mm} \text{se } m > 0\\
    n \hspace{24mm} \text{se } m = 0
    \end{array}
    \right.$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\left\{\begin{array}...\right.`, you can use `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}`...